# How do I select a row in a WPF Grid control?

Tags: wpf, grid, wpf-controls

I'm using a Grid to display data which is not known until run-time.  The XAML for my Grid is very simple since I add controls to it programmatically.  I need the grid to be flexible.

I would like the user to be able to select(highlight) the entire row in the grid and then be able to click on a button to process the data in that row.  How could I do this?

I have not been able to find any information related to my problem.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the XAML:

```
 <Grid x:Name="lstAssigned" ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     </Grid>
```

[image]

Thanks Everyone!

Here are some more details:
The data to be displayed will vary.  The grid will have 5 columns.  Columns 2 and 3 will be combo boxes.  The other columns are textBoxes.  The user will enter data and save it.

Another time, the data to be displayed could be: combo boxes in columns 2 and 4, and a date in column 5.  Since my data source will vary, I was trying to set the control type in each column programmatically.

I initially started with a DataGrid using DataTemplates, but this would define the columns and order.  Am I mistaken? I want to define them at run-time.

What would be the best way to handle this?  What type of control should I use?

I would apprectiate any kind of adice you can offer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your approach is completely wrong. Post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to implement it in WPF. You're NOT supposed to "add the controls programmatically" in WPF.

Comment: I tried to add an image, but my "Reputation" on StackOverFlow is not high enough to add one.  So I will try to give more details to my problem.

Comment: try `imgur.com` to upload the image and then put a link to the image in the question here.

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/jsrrNgX.jpg?1)

Comment: Are you telling me you did that in a `Grid` instead of a `DataGrid`? You gotta be kiddin me..

Comment: Yes I did.  I'm fairly new to WPF too.  My manager wanted it to be completely flexible and I didn't think I could do that with a DataGrid using DataTemplates.  Can I change the column definition on the fly in a DataGrid?

Comment: "Change the column definition?" What do you mean? Everything can be done, but Im not sure what you mean by that, therefore I can't tell you what's the best way to achieve it.

Comment: In a DataGrid, you can define a column as DataGridTextColumn, DataGridComboBox etc.  Can this be changed at run-time?  I also added some more details in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you should use 2 separate `DataGrid`s for each case. There are ways to alter the columns programatically in runtime, but it's more messy and leads to less maintainability. If I were given this task, I would simply use 2 Different `DataGrid`s,

one for case #1, where you need

```
Text      Combo       Combo       Text      Text
```

and the other for case #2:

```
Text      Combo       Text        Combo     DateTime
```

Sounds like a really simple set, where there are no major headaches, then you could just create a proper `DataTemplate` containing each of this `DataGrid`s for each type of Model object.

Answer (score 0):

Grid doesn't support selection of rows/columns/cells. It's used to layout controls for display. Use a something else, like a ListView instead.